# How to pass multiple values ​in a request in a get method

Tags: python, request

and during my studies I came across this problem:

Imagine this request body:

```
response =  requests.get('http://somesite/somearea/api/?key=1,2,3)
```

It is possible to pass several values ​​in the key.

I'm trying to create a function where I can pass multiples values ​​as an argument

```
def request(*data):
    d = {}
    d.update({'keys':data})
    return ('http://somesite/somearea/api/?key={}'.format(data))
```

But, the output format is incompatible:

```
request(1,2,3)

"http://somesite/somearea/api/?key=('1', '2', '3')"
```

The ideal format would be this:

```
 "http://somesite/somearea/api/?key=1,2,3"
```

I don't know if I managed to be clear in my question. I'm still starting my studies, I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tuple which you have to convert to a string:

```
def request(*data):

    return ('http://somesite/somearea/api/?key={}'.format(','.join(map(str,data))))

print (request(1,2,3))
```